# How to pass array in rails 4 strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have to pass a array of food_item_ids in my order_controller. Every order will have many food_items. How can I pass these food_items_id as an array in strong parameters.

orders_controller.rb

```
def create  
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
        if @order.save
            render :json, @order, status:201, location: [:api, @order]
        else
            render :json, { errors: @order.errors }, status:422
        end
    end

private
  def order_params

    params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :order_id, :pos_id, :table_id, :order_number, 
          :order_status,:order_date, :food_item_id => [])
  end
end
```

Is this the right way to send an array in strong params `:food_item_id => []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values:

> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric, TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.
>
> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:

```
params.permit(:id => [])
```

If it is not working, you might have a misspelling... you have asked how to pass `food_items_id`, but you are permitting the `:food_item_id => []`. So, double check the `params` you are receiving in the controller, you might have to change:

```
:food_items_id => []
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer?

**Yes**, that is how you pass an array to strong parameters.

It is worth noting that if you are passing arrays through strong parameters they must be referenced *after* all non-array parameters. In this case, however, you are already doing that.